# Do callback if an element is invalid

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have this code, validating my form:

```
   jQuery("form#theform").validate({        
        rules: {
            email_again: {
                equalTo: "#email"
            }
        }
    });
```

This works, however, I need to do function, while the email_again is not equal.  I need access to the 'element' in the function.

So, I guess the answer might look like

```
 rules: {
            email_again: {
                equalTo: "#email"
                invalidcallback: function(element){
                   // do sth with element
                }

            }
        }
    });
```

I dont find anything about this, on the docs.

---

**EDIT:**

Sparky got me almost there:

```
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true
        },
        email_again: {
            equalTo: "#email"
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        // custom code for 'email_again' field
        if (element.name === "email_again") {
            console.log('email_again in error');
        }
        // default 'highlight' code below
        if (element.type === "radio") {
            this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need to know the rule that was broken.  I need to know that it was "equalTo" so that I can find the sibling label and add a class to it:

```
jQuery(element).siblings( 'label' ).addClass('error NotEqualTo');
```

Or, if I had the equalTo "comparator" (in this case #email)  I could do the equals comparison myself and do the appropriate addClass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rules: {
    email_again: {
        // list of only methods/rules
        equalTo: "#email"  // <- this is a valid method/rule
        invalidcallback: function(element) { // <- INVALID - this is not a method/rule
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

There are no callback functions that are specific to any particular field when it's invalid.  You are only allowed to list the key:value pairs of fields:rules within the `rules` object literal.  Your desired callback function is not a recognized rule.

However, there is [a callback that's fired every time any field is invalid called `highlight`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#highlight).  Use a conditional that encapsulates the custom code for your `email_again` field.  Be sure to also include the default `highlight` code or you'll break the plugin.

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    // custom code for 'email_again' field
    if (element.name === "email_again") {
        console.log('email_again in error');
    }
    // default 'highlight' code below
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    }
}
```

**Proof-of-concept DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/r98g06kz/**

---

**EDIT**:

Since you want to alter how the classes are applied, simply tweak the default code...

```
highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
    } else {
        if (element.name === "email_again") {
            // your custom class 
            $(element).siblings( 'label' ).addClass('error NotEqualTo');
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'll also need the `unhighlight` callback as follows...

```
unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
    if (element.type === "radio") {
        this.findByName(element.name).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
    } else {
        if (element.name === "email_again") {
            // your custom class 
            $(element).siblings( 'label' ).removeClass('error NotEqualTo');
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited question, I need to know the rule that was broken, to add specific classes.

Comment: @DougCassidy, please don't edit the question to the point where the answer is disconnected and no longer makes any sense.  As far as your new request:  no, the callback functions are designed generically for all rules.  In 5,000 SO question/answers on this plugin I have not seen a way to pick out a single rule in this context.  However, I've shown you how to conditionally apply a callback based on the field `name`... just conditionally apply the class too by modifying the default code.  In this case, you'll have to also employ the `unhighlight` callback.